# Dominated convergence theorem on $e^{ix}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am considering first:

$$\lim_{n \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{ine^{ix}} dx$$

To bring the limit inside I need to apply the dominated convergence theorem. Keep in mind **I have no knowledge of measure theory...**

I was thinking if:

$$e^{ix} \le x$$ we can do something.

But we cannot compare a complex function with a real function. We **could** set a bound, $x=\pi$ such that:

$$ e^{ine^{ix}} \le e^{-in}$$

But we cannot  use the dominated convergence theorem, because we a function of $x$, $g(x)$.

I cannot prove uniform continuity either. What to do?

**The book says we CAN take the limit inside**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\left|e^{ine^{ix}}\right|=e^{n\sin x}\leq e^{|n|\sin x}\underset{\text{if }|n|\leq 1}{\leq} e\in L^1(0,\pi)$$

Comment: But we need a function of $x$

Comment: but this is a function of $x$ ! just set $f(x)=e+0x$

Comment: But the problem is with the absolute value. We need the function WITHOUT the absolute value correct?

Comment: of course not ! you should check your lesson !

Comment: I am self learning, I am not in uni yet, out of interest.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

It may be interesting for you to prove with complex analytic techniques that:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\left(in e^{ix}\right)\,dx=2\int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$$
that equals $$\frac{2\cos n}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
as $n\to +\infty$, and:
$$ \pi-2n+O(n^3) $$
as $n\to 0^+$.